# Why are these relative paths not working in php

Tags: php, path, include, relative-path

My app structure is as follows

```
application -> views -> templates
                             // some more files
                     page.php
            -> controllers 
                     home.php        
            -> models 
                     items.php
            router.php
index.php
```

**First case:**

Index.php

```
include 'application/routes.php';
```

Routes.php

```
require "controllers/home.php";
```

controllers/home.php

```
require '/application/models/clusters.php'; //works
require 'application/models/clusters.php'; //works
require '../models/clusters.php'; //doesn't work
```

Why do the first lines work but not the last?

**Second case:**

Index.php

```
include 'application/views/page.php';
```

Page.php

```
glob("application/views/templates/*.php") // array of files
glob("templates/*.php") // empty array
```

I think there's something wrong with my understanding of how paths work in php, but I can't figure out what it is. Sometimes paths seem to be relative to the current script, adn other times relative to index.php, but not necessarily tied to when I start the path with `/`

Answer (score 8):

Please try this:

```
require 'application/controllers/home.php';

require 'application/models/clusters.php';
```

The problem is that paths in PHP are always relative to the first file path, in this case index.php. So you have to include the directory 'application'.

The alternative is to use set_include_path: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.set-include-path.php

**EDIT**

To view your include_path:

```
echo ini_get('include_path');
```

Comment: If you don't want to set_include_path, but you are traversing multiple files with includes in each, `require(dirname(__FILE__).'/path');` will work

Comment: that's what I thought... so why is `"controllers/home.php";` working in application/router.php/? Something to do with `" "` vs `' '`?

Comment: Please look at Mark Baker answer for the explanation you want. We don't know your include_path values so it's hard. But i would do it like I said. I've also edited my answer to show how you can view the included path

Answer (score 0):

It always amazes me how many people don't understand the significance of include_path.

Unless you have specified an absolute path for your include/require, (i.e. a path that begins with a /) then PHP uses include_path to try and locate the file by processing each include path entry in turn. Typically, the first entry in the include path is . meaning the current directory (as returned by getcwd() if it were executed at that point in the script.

Comment: Yep that was definitely a gap in my knowledge. include_path is set to `.;[path to PEAR]`. However, I've tried running `echo getcwd();` in all the files called and it always returns the webroot folder... so it's still a mystery to me why "controllers/home.php" is included successfully

Answer (score -6):

try this one

```
require '/../models/clusters.php'; //doesn't work
```